# When using cut in a pandas dataframe to bin it, why is the binning not properly done?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, binning

I have a dataframe that I want to bin (i.e., group into sub-ranges) by one column, and take the mean of the second column for each of the bins:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Score', 'Age'])
data.Score = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -2, 1]
data.Age = [29, 59, 44, 52, 60, 53, 45, 47, 57, 54, 35, 32, 48, 31, 49, 43, 67, 32, 31, 42, 37, 45, 52, 59, 56, 57, 48, 45, 56, 31]

_, bins = np.histogram(data.Age, 10)
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]
labels[0] = '{}-{}'.format(bins[0], bins[1])
binned = pd.cut(data.Age, bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True, precision=0)
df = data.groupby(binned)['Score'].mean().reset_index()
df
```

[image]

There are 2 issues with this binning:

1. there is a gap of 1 between the upper bound of the `(n-1)`th bin and the lower bound of the `n`th bin (which means the binning is not continuous, and data points that lie in this gap are skipped).
2. the last few bin limits have a lot of digits after the decimal place. I have used the `precision=0` flag in the `cut`, but it seems to be of no use - no matter what `x` I use in `precision=x`, it still produces the bins with the last few bins having a lot of digits after the decimal point.

The second point causes problem when, for instance, I try to plot `df`, where it ruins the look of the x-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([str(i) for i in df.Age], df.Score, 'o-')
```

[image]

Why is this occurring inspite of the `precision=0` flag that I put to imply I want only integers as the bin limits, and not floats? And how do I fix it?

---

I'm temporarily solving this issue by converting the bin values to `int`s manually:

```
_, bins = np.histogram(data.Age, 10)
for i in range(len(bins)): # my fix
    bins[i] = int(bins[i])
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]
labels[0] = '{}-{}'.format(bins[0], bins[1])
binned = pd.cut(data.Age, bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True, precision=0)
df = data.groupby(binned)['Score'].mean().reset_index()
df
```

[image]

But this feels like a hack, and I think it should have a "proper" solution instead of a hacky fix. And although it fixed the second issue, I'm not sure if this fixes the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the two issues you mentioned in your question, both of them result from one line in your code which is

```
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]
```

The gab resulted from `i+1`, also the digits resulted from computer approximation in the same line.

Therefore, modify it to

```
labels = [f'{i:.1f}-{j:.1f}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]
```

in which we make an approximation to one digit.

and no need for `labels[0] = '{}-{}'.format(bins[0], bins[1])`