# pd.cut binning not working properly for partial numerical integration

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, numerical-integration, binning

There is a similar question on Stack, but it was never answered: [When using cut in a pandas dataframe to bin it, why is the binning not properly done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777825/when-using-cut-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-bin-it-why-is-the-binning-not-properly/65765682?noredirect=1#comment116277564_65765682)

I am have a dataset that I need to integrate the area under a curve, but rather than integrating the entire area under the curve at once, I am integrating partial areas at a specified interval of 5m. I.e, the area under the curve from 0-5m, 5 - 10m, 10 - 15m, etc.

However, it seems that my code is skipping the area between the last point of an interval and the first point of the next interval.

```
Here is a subset of my dataframe:

SITE    XSNO   XDIST   VERT SUB    YEAR      X     Z SOURCE     EW  \
6749  LOL  LOL006    30.0 -159.0  LI  1978.0   0.30  0.00     JF  False   
6750  LOL  LOL006    98.0 -155.0  LI  1978.0   0.98  0.04     JF  False   
6751  LOL  LOL006   148.0 -155.0  OD  1978.0   1.48  0.04     JF  False   
6752  LOL  LOL006   196.0 -133.0  OD  1978.0   1.96  0.26     JF  False   
6753  LOL  LOL006   222.0  -92.0  OD  1978.0   2.22  0.67     JF  False   
6754  LOL  LOL006   242.0 -191.0  OD  1978.0   2.42 -0.32     JF  False   
6755  LOL  LOL006   320.0 -246.0  LI  1978.0   3.20 -0.87     JF  False   
6756  LOL  LOL006   383.0 -256.0  LI  1978.0   3.83 -0.97     JF  False   
6757  LOL  LOL006   478.0 -262.0  LI  1978.0   4.78 -1.03     JF  False   
6758  LOL  LOL006   558.0 -269.0  LI  1978.0   5.58 -1.10     JF  False   
6759  LOL  LOL006   610.0 -271.0  LI  1978.0   6.10 -1.12     JF  False   
6760  LOL  LOL006   670.0 -264.0  LI  1978.0   6.70 -1.05     JF  False   
6761  LOL  LOL006   698.0 -308.0  BR  1978.0   6.98 -1.49     JF  False 


max_x = max (df.X)
interval_range = pd.interval_range(start = 0, end = max_x + 5, freq=5, closed = 'left')
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.X, bins = interval_range)

area = df.groupby(['bins', 'YEAR']).apply(lambda i: integrate.simps(i.Y, x = i.X))
```

For this subset of the data frame, my code is skipping the area between X = 4.78 and X = 5.58. I need to find a way to incorporate this into my results, I'm having trouble conceptualizing this.

Comment: Closed left means each intervals are `[a,b), [b,c)`... are you sure you are looking in the correct interval?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I've been double checking some of it by hand.